# C: Call class method without explicitly passing `this`?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I wonder if pre-processor logic / macro magic can allow one to do in C(11) as one does in typical OO languages, i.e.

```
instance->method(a, b)
```

or

```
instance.method(a, b)
```

rather than

```
method(instance, a, b) //instance is 'this'
```

?

Really it's just an ordering issue, but I'd be interested to know if anyone has achieved similar word ordering using macros. I rather like the idea of not to having to pass `this` as an explicit argument in client code on every single method call. Hence the question.

Comment: Sure - you can put function pointers in a struct. No need for macros.

Comment: @PaulR But you still have to explicitly pass `this`. Which is what I'm trying to avoid. Updated question with this fact.

Comment: @PaulR: Yes, but then you have to call `obj->funct(obj, a, b)`, which has a redundant `obj`.

Comment: OK - yes - I guess you could hide that with a macro, but things are starting to get ugly at that point.

Comment: I'll be blunt - no, no preprocessor magic can do this. 1. The function must be passed a pointer to the instance. 2. For a macro to expand to what you want (`instance->method(instance, a, b)`), it needs at minimum knowledge of the method, instance and arguments. These must be supplied through the macro arguments, since macros can't read or delete neighbouring text in, ex., `instance->MACRO(a, b)`. The bare minimum is thus `MACRO(instance, a, b)`. However, since `instance` is expanded twice, your macro could do illegal things: `MACRO(ptr++, a, b)` becomes `(ptr++)->method((ptr++), (a), (b))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GCC, you could create a macro like so:

```
#define MCALL(obj, method, ...) do {\
    typeof(obj) this;\
    this->method(this, ## __VA_ARGS__);\
  } while(0)
```

But this uses `typeof` which is a GCC extension.

It will work for no arguments, since it uses the GCC-extended `##` operator. See [this manual page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) for more information on how GCC implements variadic macros.

Of course, actually doing something like this is probably a bad idea, since you're almost re-engineering the language itself, thus making it way harder for other people to understand.

Comment: This is all I needed to know, no morality tales, just the facts - thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I can totally see doing such a thing just for fun. But I would be careful about resorting to such hackery in any code that will be used or seen by other people.

> "Always code as if the person who will maintain your code is a maniac serial killer knows where you live"

Strive for using the conventions for the language you're working in.

So either stick with `someFunc(obj, param1, param2);` or, if you can, switch to a language that supports the features you need.

Comment: Since you are hinting at that such a feature is something you'd want to use and you aren't clear on in what kind of project you intend to use it in, this kind of input might be useful although it doesn't strictly answer the question. If it makes you and your team more productive and you are willing to sacrifice some portability and maintainability then by all means use it. If it prevents some rookie browsing SO from using such hackery than that's enough to make me happy. As an aside, I don't see how my profile picture or your title has any relevance to anything (the comment you removed).

Comment: I hinted no such thing. Nor did I remove my comment. Don't waste people's time with "answers" that don't pertain directly to the question.

Comment: You are right, you said it quite plainly "I rather like the idea of not to having to pass this as an explicit argument in client code on every single method call. Hence the question". I guess from my point of view "Please don't" is an answer to "How can I bend language X into looking like language Y?". If you don't like the answer just ignore it, that's how SO usually works.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a "with params" and "no params" version, and you don't mind mismatched parentheses in your source, you could try:

```
#define MCALL( object, method )  object->method( object
```

and call it with:

```
MCALL( mything, setLength ), 57 ) ;
length = MCALL( mything, getLength ) ) ;
```

but that's pretty ugly.

Comment: Thank you, I can tell you exactly who downvoted your answer, as I have just downvoted theirs.